# Prevent links from auto hyperlinking in Outlook etc using PHP

Tags: php, regex, email, encoding, hyperlink

I know that this can be done using settings in Outlook, but that only sorts the issue for myself.

What I would like to do is use PHP to prevent text from being hyperlinked just because there is an @ sign etc...

As far as I can see, the only option for me is to encode all @ signs to their HTML numeric entity like so:

Something like this:

```
$message = str_replace('@','&#64;',$message);
```

However, if possible, I do not want this to happen if the @ sign is part of an email address.

Therefore I need something like this:

```
// SOME_REGEX will match any @ sign that is NOT part of an email address
$message = preg_replace('SOME_REGEX','&#64;',$message);
```

Can anybody think of any other better methods? Are there any flaws in this plan? Can anyone suggest a good regular expression for this? I am struggling to write a regex that **matches an @ sign if it is not part of an email address**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work if the email address is wrapped in anything not defined in the trim list.

```
$chunked_message = explode(" ", $message);

foreach($chunked_message as $chunk) {
    $clean_chunked_message[] = 
               (!filter_var(trim($chunk, " -().?!\t\r\n", FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
               ? str_replace('@', '&#64;' $chunk) : $chunk;
}

$clean_message = implode(" ", $clean_chunked_message);
```

Good luck.

Comment: This was my last resort option, although I would do it slightly differently as there may not be spaces. I would have preferred to use a regex, but I assume it is a little too complex. What I might do is filter out the email address using regex, and then replace the remaining @ signs. Pretty much the same as you but with regex. +1

Comment: Thanks. I prefer avoiding regex unless it's either ideal for the job or the only option, as it does add noticeable overhead to the task. It may take less lines, but at the cost of loading the regex engine.

Comment: I could not agree more, I rarely use it but I always use it for email address validation as the `filter_var` function is a little unreliable like in this case...

Comment: I only say that because of the space issue, however, I have just realised why that space issue occurred, nothing to do with the `filter_var`. In that case, it is reliable, I am just being stupid! :-). Will accept as the answer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature of mail application to detect link when it is found and make it click able.

A dirty trick to escape this situation is to use space in between the links.

Example:

```
http://ww w.you tube.com/v=.......
```

Comment: This is not what I am trying to achieve. I want to ignore valid links and make them clickable, if the application supports it. But, I want to make sure that non-links (specifcally email addresses) are not converted to hyperlinks just because they have an @ sign. For instance, Outlook converted the following to a 'mailto' link: `_~@><,./;'#][=-`. Yes, it is very unlikely that this arrangement of characters will be present in an email, but my point remains the same. This is not an email address, yet Outlook hyperlinked it!

Comment: @BenCarey, I dont think there is much we can do on this. Its still a feature from outlook itself.

Comment: That is exactly what I thought, but surely if I encode the @ signs then a hyperlink will not be created by Outlook or any other email client! That is why I want a regex to replace the non-email address @ signs with the encoded entity

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `_~@><,./;'#][=-` is a pornographic emoticon.

Comment: @Anthony hahahaha, probably is... Was just testing random characters for encoding issues and came across the hyperlink bug. That is my reasoning for the very random selection